# split persian(arabic) number with sscanf

Tags: c, persian

i have a persian text like : " ۲۲۸
در صورتي که موضوع تعهد، تأديه‌ي وجه نقدي باشد، حاکم مي‌تواند با رعايت ماده‌ي ۲۲۱ مديون را به جبران خسارت حاصله از تأخير در تأديه دين محکوم نمايد." and my goal is to split "۲۲۸" that is a number from the main text, if it was a normal english number i could do it easily by

```
sscanf(text,"%d %[^\t\n]", &a);
```

but c does not recognize persian number as decimal. so what should i do ?

as i do some research i know that objective-c recognize this text as utf-8, and one way to solve this is to replace numbers with english ones .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do is, to show numbers in Persian but send those numbers in English.
All you have to do is to have a convertor in UI which converts everything to Persian as the user is inputting his text. But send the original text to your app.

If your case is just about numbers, you may want to have a convertor for numbers only.

*BTW, it is just the solution we use and is tested. However, you may find a better one.*

---

**UPDATED**
In this case (that you are unable to modify user's input), you have to try these steps:
**First** try to understand how these numbers are encoded. *Write a sample application which receives Persian numbers as characters and print them to see what they really are*
**Second** have a 2D array consisting of `number-encoded-character` and its `real value`. Store all of the ten numbers in it.
**Third** receive the whole text as a string and find numbers in that. (*Because now you are able to compare each character by those encoded-number-characters*). As soon as there is a match in your look up table, you can have its real value.

Comment: problom is the sources are not generated by myself so this opetion is not available

Comment: So you are just receiving the text? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why don't you try to see how those Persian numbers are encoded? I updated my answer.